# Change userLocation puck color using MapBox v10

Tags: swift, mapbox-ios, userlocation

I’m working on migrating my MapBox version from `v6.4` to `v10`.

I have been able to migrate almost everything, only issue I have at the moment is changing the userLocation puck tintColor.

What I was doing on `v6.4` was changing the color in `mapView.tintColor` where `mapView` is an object of `MKMapView` class.
Right now, changing the `tintColor` will only update the `attributionButton` color.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I was just asking myself the same question :) Did you figure out how to change the color? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As of Mapbox v10.4.3, the solution that works for me is by adding a custom circle image with solid color instead.

```
 let configuration = Puck2DConfiguration(topImage: UIImage(named: "circleSolidColor"))
 mapView.location.options.puckType = .puck2D(configuration)
```